# How to include an HTML file with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make my code separate so I decided to divide each `div` to html files. Each HTML file has some jQuery click events. I have 2 files `index.html` and `menu.html`.

Problem is that I have to include the jQuery library in both files to make it work.

Is there any way that I can include library one time and have it work on both files? I tried to include the library in the  index page only, but then the menu click doesn't work.

I included the `menu.html` file through an iframe.

```
<iframe src="left-menu.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add `menu.html` into the DOM of `index.html` with the jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. This way the jQuery instance created in `index.html` would also apply to the content loaded from `menu.html`.

For example in `index.html` you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some-menu').load('some-local-path/menu.html');
});
```

Note how `$('#some-menu')` is just another element in `index.html` into which we load the contents of `menu.html`. It's also important to note that because of the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), the AJAX request performed as part of the `load()` method would only work with files in the same domain, protocol and port (unless you're using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

Comment: this would be a cleaner solutions as opposed to using iframes

Comment: @Joji This still seems to work. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/n492fgd3/ You might be encountering a CORS error. Please check for errors.

Answer (score 11):

In your HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
     <div data-includeHTML="_HeaderPartial.html"></div>
</header>
<main>
    <div>
        This is the main content, from the index file
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <div data-includeHTML="_FooterPartial.html"></div>
</footer>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[data-includeHTML]").each(function () {                
            $(this).load($(this).attr("data-includeHTML"));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

In a separate file "_HeaderPartial.html":

```
<div>
    <h1>This is the Header from its _Partial file</h1>
</div>
```

In a separate file "_FooterPartial.html":

```
<strong>And this is from the footer partial file</strong>
```

The result:

### This is the Header from its _Partial file

This is the main content, from the index file

**And this is from the footer partial file**

Answer (score 4):

I have another solution. 
It seems to make code more beautiful and shorter.
First define include function.

```
var include = function(beReplacedId,url){
jQuery.get(url,function(data){
    jQuery(beReplacedId).replaceWith(data);

});
```

}

On html page use onload to trigger include like this.

```
<img id="partTopicDetail" onload="include(this,this.id+'.html')" src="img/any-image.png" >
```

After the compiler runs through it will replace img tag and load what you need.
With above trick i can attach to any place in my index.html