# javascript alternative to php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What is the javascript equivalent to PHP's `include(file.html)` specifically without needing to place it in a div like `$("#div").load("file.html");`? I'd like to get away from using PHP and find out how to do this in Javascript **without using a div placeholder** and just loading it into webcode to use with things like bootstrap modals or buttons.

Comment: You're already using jQuery's `load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/ so what's the problem you're having?

Comment: If you just need to append content to the body it's fine otherwise you need a target element (division or anything else) to tell the ajax callback where to put the content in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include an HTML file with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320801/how-to-include-an-html-file-with-jquery)

Comment: got to placed be in the DOM somewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file?rq=1

Comment: If you're looking to get away from PHP, another possible solution would be SSI `.shtml` or treat `.html` files as SSI.

Comment: take it up with the person who's given you an answer below if you're not going to comment or tell us otherwise that those 2 links we've included aren't duplicates.

Comment: hey Fred, can you expand on treating the `.html` files as SSI? I read something about that awhile back but can't quite pull it out of my memory...

Comment: you'd need to do that through `.htaccess` if your system supports it. You running on Apache? however, can't you just rename your ext. to `.shtml`? be easier. Most systems are already setup to SSI with `.shtml`.

Comment: content included by js\jquery will not be indexed(google) like that included via php, if that matters

Comment: Ok I'll give those both a shot Fred, and thank you Dagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, php acts as a preprocessor - it sees that include line, fetches the html and then drops the contents of the file in-place. Javascript can't really do that in the same way because it only lives on the browser.

You have some options

1. Do you an http request to a resource that will return the html, and then render that html string to a location (html id tag of some sort)
2. Use a different preprocessor. There's loads and it depends on what runtime you're on. NodeJS? Ruby? Go? Java? Python? All of them use something different - but they'll give you a one-to-one alternative for the directives you want to use inside your html files. Here's a great article that gives an overview of a number of different options: https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/

Comment: his example is `file.html` i would net expect any php processing to be required. And as the request is made through the server, even if it was full of php, that would be server passed

Comment: I'd like to stick with javascript/jquery for this as my logic will also be done using them.

Comment: @Dagon true. I guess I was thinking that since OP wanted a directive replacement, it would make sense to just use a different preprocessor to achieve that.

OP If that's the case then the only way is to load and attach it to a container, because if not - where is the html supposed to go?

Comment: It's a rubbish question, i wouldn't bother with it myself usually.

Answer (score 0):

naturally, when you want to load a resource from js (when it is possible and do not try to access a resource that triggers a cross domain origin problem) you use **AJAX**

a simple implementation using jQuery:

```
$.get('file.html', function(file) {
  console.dir(file);
});
```